# QMenuBar only contains inactive menu items on OS X

Tags: c++, macos, qt, osx-mavericks, qmenubar

For some reason all my menu bar items are greyed out when I use the native menu bar on OS X Mavericks:

[image: menu bar]

I create the menu actions using the following code:

```
newAct = new QAction(tr("&New"), this);
newAct->setShortcuts(QKeySequence::New);
newAct->setStatusTip(tr("New"));
newAct->setShortcutContext(Qt::ApplicationShortcut);
newAct->setEnabled(true);
newAct->setAutoRepeat(false);
addAction(newAct);
connect(newAct, SIGNAL(triggered()), this, SLOT(newFile()));
...
```

These actions are then added to the menubar like this:

```
// _menuBar = new QMenuBar(0);
_menuBar = menuBar();
//_menuBar->setNativeMenuBar(false);

fileMenu = _menuBar->addMenu(tr("&File"));
fileMenu->addAction(newAct);
```

Uncommenting the first line shows the same behaviour. It does however work fine when I use the the non-native menu bar.

Qt version:

```
$ /usr/local/qt/5.3/clang_64/bin/qmake -v    
QMake version 3.0
Using Qt version 5.3.1 in /usr/local/qt/5.3/clang_64/lib
```

Any ideas/suggestions?

Comment: Hi, were you able to identify the reason of this problem? I have encountered it as well with Qt 5.5. With Qt 4.8.6 things work ok but with Qt 5.5 all the menu items are inactive.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect this line is your culprit:

```
addAction(newAct);
```

You shouldn't be adding the QActions to your window, since you'll be adding them to the fileMenu object instead.  Try removing the above line.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I just tried removing the addAction() line, but the menu looked the same. I'm adding them to get the shortcuts working, how would you go about it if you're not adding it to the window otherwise? Add another action with the same setup? Anyway, this unfortunately didn't resolve my problem.

Comment: Hmm.  Can you post a small, self-contained, compilable example program that reproduces the fault?

Comment: Well, I just tried that, but if I create a fresh project in Qt Creator and copy over the relevant stuff it works. What I didn't mention is that I'm not using qmake directly to build my project, but instead I integrated it into a project based on autotools via autotroll, which worked just fine up until now. Chances are that this is somehow causing problems with the menu bar.. :-/

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.

Setting the `windowModality` property of my MainWindow to `NonModal` worked for me.